# I discard unstaged changes but they remain as unstage changes and it don't let me pull from remove

Tags: git

I've type

```
git checkout -- .
```

To discard changes and then `git pull origin <branch-name>` but for some reason, the changes remain there and I don't know what I can also do.

The fact the changes remains unstaged makes git doesn't allow me to do a `git pull`

I also tried to stash changes, but the unstaged changes stay in place when typing `git status`.

Help me, please

Comment: It would help to have the output of `git pull` and `git status` to better identify the problem. Is the file causing problems actually with unstaged changes, or untracked? `git checkout -- .` only reverts unstaged changes, and leaves untracked files as is.

Comment: If you really used `--.` (no space between `--` and `.`), you should have gotten an error. If you used something else, well, you didn't copy-paste what you did use, so we can't be sure we're seeing what you actually saw. This is why it's important to be careful when describing the problem. See also [ask].

Comment: All that said, I'm *guessing* that you have a setup where someone has used a Linux system to create a commit that cannot be checked out correctly on your Windows system. If that's the case, you'll just need to set up a Linux system to work with this commit.